# UE4 does not have the "Add Code to Project" menu option

Tags: unreal-engine4

I am following the Programming Quickstart guide for the first time.  I experienced "out of video memory" error on the first page of this: 
https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/QuickStart/1/index.html

and then the next page:
https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Programming/QuickStart/2/index.html
shows a File menu item called "Add Code to Project" but my system does not have that.  It does not have anything "Project" or "Actors" like the web page shows.

Without a working quickstart guide I am completely stuck.  Help!

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe post a screenshot of your File-Menu dropdown? Also, what version of the engine do you use?

For the "out of video memory" error you could try and lower the quality setting of your editor (see screenshot).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.  I found this "out of video memory" problem all over the internet, and Unreal has not answered it.

Its actually quite simple.  I have two GPUs in my computer, and UE4 grabs the small one instead of the big one.  I wonder why they don't know about this and fix it.

All you have to do is right click the UE4 icon and select "Run with Graphics Processor" and then select the best one you have.

Now I suppose that my application will also grab the wrong GPU....